# Recursive print of binary number

Tags: c, recursion

I'm struggling to write a recursive way to print a binary number. Here is what I have so far:

```
int bin(unsigned char n)
{
    if (n==0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("%d", bin(n<<1));
    }
}

bin(7)
```

What seems to be wrong with the logic above?

Comment: With `bin(0)` it prints nothing.  I'd expect a way to print a binary number would produce `"0"`.

Comment: Save time and enable all warnings.  carl.hiass, Where does `int bin()` return a value when `n==0` is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few errors such as using `<<` (shift up) instead of `>>` (shift down). Also not always returning something. I'm surprised the compiler didn't pull you up on that. You don't gain anything from a return value, So you may as well get rid of it.

A simple implementation could look like this. We need to have the wrapped function (`bin_recur`) to allow us to differentiate between 0 the input value and 0 which signifies its time to stop recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bin_recur(unsigned char n)
{
    if (n > 0) 
    {
        printf("%d", n & 1);
        bin_recur(n >> 1);
    }
}

void bin(unsigned char n)
{
    if (n == 0) 
    {
        printf("0\n");
    } else 
    {
        bin_recur(n);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        bin(i);
    }
}
```

The fact that your `bin` function calls `printf` is not completely ideal.  This is what's known as [tight coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) and the function could be more reusable if it was not bound to how it is presented. Perhaps copying to a string is a good way or even using `fprintf` to print to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Stopping when `n` is 0 is wrong.

This fails for the trivial case where `n` is 0 to start with.

What you really need to do is pass down a shift amount as a second argument and stop after 8 bits.

Using the `return` with value just gets in the way.

Here's some refactored code with a full diagnostic test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
bin2(unsigned char n,int shf)
{

    if (shf <= 7) {
        bin2(n,shf + 1);
        printf("%d", (n >> shf) & 1);
    }
}

void
bin(unsigned char n)
{

    bin2(n,0);
}

int
main(void)
{

    for (unsigned int chr = 0; chr <= 0xFF; ++chr) {
        printf("%2.2X: ", chr);
        bin((unsigned char) chr);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please add this lines to your code.

```
  void binary(int n) {
     if(n==0)
        return;

    binary(n/2);
    printf("%d",n%2);
}
```

Comment: or you can add binary(n>>1) for division by 2.

Comment: sir language is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `print` call to execute after the recursive function for this to work. Here's an example:

```
void bin(unsigned char n)
{
    if (n > 1) bin(n>>1);
    putchar(n&1 ? '1' : '0');
}

int main(void)
{
    for (unsigned char i = 255; i; i--) {
        printf("%d --> ", i), bin(i);
        getchar(); // inspect element if you want
    }
}
```

Link to running code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/r1P3biNMu).